# PDO func insert and multiplilcation

Tags: javascript, php, pdo, sql-insert

im trying to make function that take every row from column inv by user id multiply it by 0,015 and then insert this value to zhod with same user id.

i have this but im lost already. if someone can help or simplify it ill be glad.

```
public function updateZhod($id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE users 
                SET zhod = inv * 0.015 
            WHERE id = :id 
            AND verified = 1";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'fetchAllUsersInv') {
    $output = '';
    $data = $admin->fetchAllUsersInv(0);
    if ($data) {
        $output .= '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Inv</th>
                                <th>Zhod</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';

        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $zhodValue = $row['inv'] * 0.015;

            $output .= '<tr>
                            <td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row['inv'] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $zhodValue . '</td>
                        </tr>';
        }

        $output .= '</tbody>
                    </table>';

        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo '<h3 class="text-center text-secondary">:( No inv</h3>';
    }
}


if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'updateZhod') {
    $admin->updateZhod();

    echo 'Zhod values updated successfully!';
}
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#zhodLed").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'assets/php/admin-action.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'updateZhod'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        $("#invValue").text(response.newValue.toFixed(2) + " ...");
                    } else {
                        alert("Error: Failed to update zhod value.");
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.error("AJAX Error:", textStatus, errorThrown);
                    alert("Error: Unable to make the AJAX request.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this should be simple func that take one value from inv multiply it by 0,015 and insert it to zhod but its probably behind my skills

Comment: If you want to multiply all users by the same amount then you don't need the WHERE clause. Just update all the rows in one statement.  Or at least you could only remove the `id = :id AND` part so that it only updates verified users

Comment: So then also `function updateZhod($id)` can become `function updateZhod()`, which would match the way you're calling it (which doesn't involve any ID values). And you would need to remove the `$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);` line as well, obviously

Comment: good point removed id. but when i click it nothing happens and no errors.... edit: console after click : admin-dashboard.php:331  AJAX Error: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.min.js:2:77349
    at l (jquery.min.js:2:77466)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:80265)

Comment: Well `Zhod values updated successfully!` isn't JSON, it's just a plain string. But you told jquery to expect JSON in the response. So inevitably there is an error when it tries and fails to parse the response from PHP as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your intents from the question

*im trying to make function that take **every** row from column inv by user id multiply it by 0.015 and then insert this value to zhod with same user id.*

And then I read your Javascript, which calls the PHP function with no parameter other than an action, I mean you dont pass an `id` parameter or anything else.

Then I think you are saying you want to do this all in one go, so no need to read all the data before running the query. So the query could simply be

```
$sql = "UPDATE users 
                SET zhod = inv * 0.015 
        WHERE verified = 1";
$this->conn->query($sql);
```

Your code could then just select all the changed data and send it back to the javascript as HTML which you could simply place in a location of the page using the javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Move your admin block in the loop by userId, with it's id parameter:

```
$admin->updateZhod($row['id']);
```

Btw: you need a flag to multiply this value one time, in order to prevent more than once multiplication with every action.